How to install numpy on python 3.10 running on ubuntu 22.04
I need to have numpy on python3.10 on my ubuntu 22.04 .
Here is what I get when I attempt to install it:
$ sudo apt install python3.10 python3-numpy python3-mako python3-markupsafe \
  python3-yaml python3-ruamel.yaml xterm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-markupsafe is already the newest version (2.0.1-2build1).
python3-markupsafe set to manually installed.
python3-yaml is already the newest version (5.4.1-1ubuntu1).
python3-yaml set to manually installed.
xterm is already the newest version (372-1ubuntu1).
python3-mako is already the newest version (1.1.3+ds1-2ubuntu0.1).
python3-mako set to manually installed.
python3.10 is already the newest version (3.10.12-1~22.04.3).
python3.10 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-numpy : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or
                          liblapack.so.3

$ sudo apt install liblapack3
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have    
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable    
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
 
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) 
but 2.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed.


Unless you have a very specific reason to use Numpy from the Ubuntu repos, the preferred way of installation is using pip, which is Python's standard tool for installing Python modules without conflicting the system's package. Ideally the instillation should take place in a venv, which is considered "best practice" for Python.
The Numpy version in the 22.04 Ubuntu repos is 1.21.5, which dates back to spring 2022. The most current version (at the time of writing) is 2.0.1 and 1.26.4, the latter if you want to stick to the 1.x branch of Numpy. Both were released within this year (2024). And even 1.21.5 is not the last bugfix release of the 1.21 branch, this is 1.21.6.
To install a newer respectively the newest version, follow the following steps:
First, install the required packages from Ubuntu's sources:
sudo apt install build-essential python3-pip python3-venv

Switch to your home directory (or any other directory where your user rights allow the reading and writing files) and create a venv:
python3 -m venv numpy_venv

numpy_venv is the name of the venv, can be freely chosen.
Switch into the venv's directory and activate the venv:
cd numpy_venv
source bin/activate

Now you can install numpy using pip:
pip3 install numpy

This will install the latest version of Numpy. If you like a different version, e.g. the latest release of the 1.x branch, write numpy==1.26.4 instead of numpy in the above command.
Once installation is finished, you can run the Python Interpreter within the venv
python3

and then import numpy
>>> import numpy

Under 22.04, this works also without a venv on a user level. To do so, simply skip the steps in creating and activating the venv and just run the installation command. This will install numpy for the user executing the command.

You need to satisfy the dependency liblapack3, which can be installed via the following command:
sudo apt install liblapack3

Ensure other system packages are up-to-date with:
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

Additionally, you can try to fix the dependencies with:
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Please copy the entire output of the apt commands (and format as "code") to assist with debugging.

Thank you for your suggestion. After I tried to install liblapack3, I received the following error:

Thanks for the suggestion.Got an error message:
eading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed

You may want to install the build-essential, which should make sure you have standard tools for building, like gcc, gfortran, etc.
